# Define sequence of document.ready() functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

In the old jquery one could add a function to the top of document.ready like this:

```
$.readyList.unshift(function () {
```

Now this is not possible anymore. Is there another way to move one function to the top? Our ASP.NET pages consist of different controls that all have their own document.ready, so it is currently impossible for me to change this. But I need one function to run before all others.

Is there another "clean" way to do this?

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example of what you mean? What's stopping you from running conditionals at the top of document.ready() to call the functions you need?

Comment: We have multiple controls that are built by multiple developers. So it is complicated to change them all.

Comment: So why not set as first ready handler your function? Set it just after including jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/readylist-is-no-longer-exposed-in-1-4):

> It's due to the fact that ready is (and should be) an event - the fact
>   that some of the internals were exposed was a mistake (one that we're
>   working to rectify). As you mentioned it was undocumented and its
>   exposure was unintended.

Though I'm not sure what prevents you from writing your own list (or extend jquery) with a new readyList:

```
var readyList = [func1, func2, func3 ...];
```

and executing it one by one in `.ready()`:

Comment: I don't really have control over all functions. While it is possible, I would have hoped for a different solution.

Comment: You could probably put that function call at the bottom of the HTML page in a script tag :p

Answer (score 3):

Use `holdready`.

from [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.holdReady/):

```
$.holdReady(true);
//your function that must be first...
$.holdReady(false);
```

Comment: But this could be executed before the document is actually ready, no?

Comment: It should be executed before document is ready. It holds the actual event from firing.

Comment: Yeah, that does not really help :-(

Comment: If you put the function between these it should fire first.
Also The document itself is ready but you so you should be able to manipulate it but it holds the other ready functions from firing.